# How do I add --with-ssl to Homebrew's litmus install

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to add litmus with ssl enabled, but the "download - configure - make" path fails, missing files . So tried Homebrew Install Litmus and it works fine - but... it doesn't build with ssl, which I need it to do.
Thanks

Comment: Editing my own posts again - Do this: brew edit litmus and add the --with-ssl after the prefix bit.

Comment: So I fell over that - macports is installed, so I installed litmus with macports - and it works.